# Do you need both JWT and Passport in a Node app?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to understand the user login authentication process for a MERN app I'm building. So many tutorials I see use both `passport` with `jwt`, and I'm having a hard time understanding why I would use both together instead of just one or the other. My preference would be to use `jwt`, but if there's a reason not to then I'll use `passport`, or both.

For example, here's a `/login` route, which returns a `jwt` to the user:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  let query = { email: req.body.email };
  let entered_password = req.body.password;

  User.findOne(query, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ message: "Invalid authorization" });
    }

    // returned from user object stored in mongodb
    let bcrypted_password = user.password;

    // put password entered on login page through bcrypt and compare it to the hashed password
    bcrypt.compare(entered_password, bcrypted_password, (error, isMatch) => {
      if (error) { console.log(error); }
      else {

        if (isMatch) {

          // passwords match, so create a jwt token for user
          jwt.sign({ email: req.user.email },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            { expiresIn: "24h" },
            (jwt_err, token) => {

            if (jwt_err) {
              return res.sendStatus(402);
            }

            else {
              // token created, now return it to user
              return res.json({ token });
            }
          });
        }

        else { // passwords do not match
          return res.json({ message: "Invalid authorization" });
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This `jwt` is returned to the user and stored in `localStorage`. Then when a user tries to access a protected route, I send the token and have a `verifyToken` middleware to check if the token is valid:

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.body.token;
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, authData) => {
    if(err) {
      res.json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
    }
    else {
      // verification worked
      next();
    }
  });
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there anything wrong with this? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using `jwt` with or without `passport`?

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar approach as outlined by you in this post and haven’t found a need to use passport.

Passprt isn’t required, although it can be easier for people to get going (and potentially avoid security pitfalls).

If you are competent, then a custom solution is acceptable. Personally I place the JWT signed UserId in the cookie, check for it with middleware and then add it to the request object (making it available with `req.userId` As opposed to `req.body`)

Comment: No worries, someone may have a better answer/case for/against Passport for you, this is just my two cents.